# Classify users based on demographics

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification, analytics, prediction

I am working on a personal project just for fun. Basically I have collected the data which has demographic information about each country like :

Germany 74% male 26% female 10% married 16% Age_30-35 40% etc

Now what I want to do is when I get a new user, I see that user's country and try to predict information about the user ie if the user is a male who is married and of age 30-35 (just an example).

My question is how can I make such prediction , I can't just make a rule which says if a country has more than 50% male, the new user from this country is also male. Basically I want to know how can I decide on the value which would help me predict the users demographics with certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a prediction but rather a probability question since you can just calculate all probabilities if you have values as described.

**Here's an example:**

```
Male population = 74%
People married = 16% 
People between 30-35 = 40%
```

To get the probability for a new German user to be male, married and between 30-35 years old you do the following:

```
P(Male|Married|30-35) = p(Male) * p(Married) * p(30-35)
P(Male|Married|30-35) = 0,74 * 0,16 * 0,40 = 0,04736 ~ 4,7%
```

You don't need more to calculate this. If you however want to classify all users automatically I suggest you take a look at [Naive Bayes Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier).

Comment: Thank you very much. It was helpful.